# lookup group ID, concatenate vertical list by group, and display results

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two worksheets. The first worksheet `items` has a few rows with unique IDs in column A (item), a lookup list ID in column B (list), a blank column C (choices) where I want my solution to go, and a column D showing my desired output for Column C.

[image]

The second sheet `choices` contains a column with the list IDs (list) that links to the list ID (list) in the `items` worksheet. It also contains a column `choices` associated with each list.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is concatenate the choices by list (e.g., A, B, C for list1) and display the result in the `items` worksheet (Col C choices).

I'm looking for a solution that will update automatically as I add more content to both worksheets. Also, as I continue to review other ideas, it's worth noting that I cannot rely on sorting in my solution.

Comment: What excel are you using?  If not the latest Office 365 then it will require vba.

Comment: thanks. Excel for Mac 2011, 14.6.3. i could upgrade if the solution is easier.

Comment: No, the TEXTJOIN() Function is not available on the Mac.  It will require vba.

Comment: ok, thanks. any tips on how to go about creating the vba solution? relevant examples maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with sorting in `choices`, then this appears to work:

[image]

[image]

h/t: http://www.exceltactics.com/combine-data-multiple-rows-one-cell/5/

Comment: You stated `it's worth noting that I cannot rely on sorting in my solution.` hence the vba is the only route statement.  If you were okay sorting then I would have suggested this method.

Comment: that makes sense. i'm looking for a non-sorting option, but i figured i would post this as a partial solution.